# onChange on array inside the object reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [state,setState]={
    "abc": 0,
    "bce": 0,
    "sal": 0,
    "mek": [
      {

        "entityid": 0,
        "ol": 0,
        "salincomeId": 0,
        "jCK": 0,
        "description": "",
        "AMT": 0,
        "AA": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

i have this object ,i am handing it with onChange Event this works fine for outer object I am not able ,
onChange mek the array inside the object

```
const handleInput=(event,name)=>{

    const value=event.target.value

    setState({
      ...State,
      [event.target.name]:value
    })
```

how can i put values to mek here

Comment: The formatting of your answer is messed up, can you clean up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score -1):

I guess something like this. But you need to consider that it's an array.

```
const {value, name} = event.target;

this.setState((state) => ({
    ...state, mek[0]: { ...state.mek[0], [name]: [value] }
}))
```

Comment: const {value, name} = event.target;

this.setState((state) => ({
    ...state, mek[0]: { ...state.mek[0], [name]: [value] }
}))   this way its accessing the correct variable which is 'description' but after i start writing anything it throw an error ,Cannot read property 'description' of undefined